# Access Child elements of an Anchor tag on click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have the below html

```
<a id='quoteLinks' class='quoteLinksClass'>
  <span data-action='viewQuote'>
    <i data-action='viewQuote' data-quoteid ="2" class="fa fa-eye"></i>
  </span>

  <span data-action='editQuote'>
    <i data-action='editQuote' data-quoteid ="3" class="fa fa-eye"></i>
  </span>
</a>
```

If the user clicks on the span section of the anchor tag, I want to perform different actions accordingly. Like - 'Edit Quote' or 'View Quote' as above

I have the following jQuery snippet:

```
$('.quoteLinksClass').on('click',function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  if(event.target.nodeName == 'SPAN' || event.target.nodeName == 'I'){
    var quoteId = $(this).data('quoteid');
    var action  = $(this).data('action');
    console.log($(this)); // Here it prints the <a> object, but I 
                            // need   <span> or <i> based on the click
    if(action == 'viewQuote') {
      window.location.href="view page";
    } else if(action == 'editQuote') {
      window.location.href="edit page";
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: so what is the problem with the code

Comment: I get the variable quoteId as undefined as $(this) is representing the <a> object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `event.target` along with `.closest()` to find the actual `span` which was clicked and then access the `data-*` attributes associated with the spans as below

```
<a id='quoteLinks' class='quoteLinksClass'>
    <span data-action='viewQuote' data-quoteid ="2">
        <i  class="fa fa-eye"></i>
    </span>

    <span data-action='editQuote' data-quoteid ="3">
        <i  class="fa fa-eye"></i>
    </span>
</a>
```

then

```
$('.quoteLinksClass').on('click', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();

    var $span = $(event.target).closest('span');
    var quoteId = $span.data('quoteid');
    var action = $span.data('action');
    if (action == 'viewQuote') {
        window.location.href = "view page";
    } else if (action == 'editQuote') {
        window.location.href = "edit page";
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6khd5g70/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.quoteLinksClass').on('click','span,i',function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();

     var quoteId = $(this).data('quoteid');
     if(quoteId.length ==0 ) {
       quoteId = $(this).find('i').data('quoteid');
     }

      var action  = $(this).data('action');
      if(action == 'viewQuote'){
        window.location.href="view page";
      }
      else if(action == 'editQuote'){
        window.location.href="edit page";
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at $(this)
`this` => `event.target`

```
$('.quoteLinksClass').on('click',function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  if(event.target.nodeName == 'SPAN' || event.target.nodeName == 'I'){
    var quoteId = $(event.target).data('quoteid');
    var action  = $(event.target).data('action');
    console.log($(this)); // Here it prints the <a> object, but I 
                                // need   <span> or <i> based on the click
    if(action == 'viewQuote') {
      window.location.href="view page";
    } else if(action == 'editQuote') {
      window.location.href="edit page";
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `click` event on `span` and check the `action`.

```
$('.quoteLinksClass').on('click', 'span', function (event) {
  var action = $(this).data('action');
  if (action === 'viewQuote') {

  } else if (action === 'editQuote') {

  }
});
```

This will make separations of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.quoteLinksClass > span').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var that = $(this);
  var action = that.attr('data-action');
  if (action == 'viewQuote') {
    alert('viewQuote');
  } else if (action == 'editQuote') {
    alert('editQuote');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id='quoteLinks' class='quoteLinksClass'>
  <span data-action='viewQuote'>
    <i data-action='viewQuote' data-quoteid ="2" class="fa fa-eye"></i>View
  </span>

  <span data-action='editQuote'>
    <i data-action='editQuote' data-quoteid ="3" class="fa fa-eye"></i>Edit
  </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just make two links out of it. Currently your JavaScript knows quite a lot about your HTML structure. Since you have the quote-id on every span element how about just doing:

```
<span data-action='viewQuote' data-quoteid ="2">
    <i  class="fa fa-eye"></i>
</span>

<span data-action='editQuote' data-quoteid ="3">
    <i  class="fa fa-eye"></i>
</span>
```

and then in your JS:

```
$('*[data-action="viewQuote"]').on('click', function() {
     var quoteId = $(this).data('quoteid');
     window.location.href="viewQuote?quoteId="+quoteId;
}

$('*[data-action="editQuote"]').on('click', function() {
     var quoteId = $(this).data('quoteid');
     window.location.href="editQuote?quoteId="+quoteId;
}
```

That way your code doesn't need to know anything about your HTML layout, it just needs to know about your data attributes. You also save some ifs and elses :D.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.quoteLinksClass span i').on('click',function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    if(event.target.nodeName == 'SPAN' || event.target.nodeName == 'I'){
      var quoteId = $(this).data('quoteid')
      var action  = $(this).data('data-action');
      console.log($(this)); // Here it prints the <a> object, but I 
                              // need   <span> or <i> based on the click
      if(action == 'viewQuote') {
        window.location.href="view page";
      } else if(action == 'editQuote') {
        window.location.href="edit page";
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<a id='quoteLinks' class='quoteLinksClass' href="#">
  <span data-action='viewQuote'>
    <i data-action='viewQuote' data-quoteid ="2" class="fa fa-eye"></i>
  </span>

  <span data-action='editQuote'>
    <i data-action='editQuote' data-quoteid ="3" class="fa fa-eye"></i>
  </span>
</a>
```